# UIPickerView - How to detect the value changed programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview, onchange

`- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component` delegate just don't work when the value changed programmatic

i.e.

`[pickerView selectRow:5 inComponent:2 animated:YES];`

How to detect `UIPickerView` is set the value?

Answer (score 0):

Try below:-

// Set the delegate and datasource. Don't expect picker view to work
 // correctly if you don't set it.

```
   [pickerView setDataSource: self];
    [pickerView setDelegate: self]
```

First, let the selection indicator (that line inside the
 // picker view that highlights your selection) to be shown.

```
   pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
```

// Allow us to pre-select the fiifth option in the pickerView.

```
   [pickerView selectRow:5 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```